# How to use typealias when getting data from server

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

I am trying to get user data from a server. The application does not have to show any views until the data is loaded.
I read about typealias and I don't understand how to use it.

What I want: when data is loaded, move on to next step. If failed, load data again.

Here's how I declare typealias

```
typealias onCompleted = () -> ()
typealias onFailed = () -> ()
```

Here is my request code

```
 func getUserData(_ completed: @escaping onCompleted, failed: @escaping onFailed){

        let fullURL = AFUtils.getFullURL(AUTHURL.getUserData)

        AFNetworking.requestGETURL(fullURL, params: nil, success: {
            (JSONResponse) -> Void in

            if let status = JSONResponse["status"].string {
                switch status{
                case Status.ok:
                    completed()
                    break
                default:
                    failed()
                    break
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

But how could I use this on my view controller when calling getUserData?

Comment: Why are you using `AFNetworking` with `Swift`? There's [`Alamofire`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), framework from the same devs, doing same stuff, only written in `Swift`.

Comment: If this is the real code structure I would return `JSONResponse` rather than two separate objects and do the `switch` in the calling method. And if it's only a `true` / `false` question I would return one `(Bool) -> ()`

Comment: Don't concentrate on AFNetworking, AF is my project initials I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Comment: As a side note, I recommend capitalizing your typealiases as `OnCompleted` and `OnFailure` (or, maybe better yet, `CompletedBlock` and `FailureBlock`). Typealiases represent types, as its name suggests, and types use capitalized names.

Comment: What is not working as intended?

Comment: I also recomment using `Gloss` with `Alamofire`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your custom `AFNetworking.requestGETURL`s completion handler is called on the main queue:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getUserData({
        //do somthing and update ui
    }) {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

How I understand your comment, you actually want to name your completion and error block parameters. If so, change the method to :

```
func getUserData(completion completed: @escaping onCompleted, error failed: @escaping onFailed){ ... }
```

and call it like this:

```
getUserData(completion: { 
    //do somthing and update ui
}, error: {
    //handle error
})
```

Comment: It's great to calling this but how could call getUserDate when called error completion block